# Umbraco 8 Model builder not unable to find doctype generated file

Tags: c#, model, umbraco, builder, umbraco8

I am working on an existing Umbraco 8 project and seeing some very strange behaviour. I created a doctype via my localhost and it generated the doctype.generated.cs file added it to visual studio and everything was fine.

When it came to deploy the changes, I went into Model Builder regenerated the models, saw them appear in the folder, went to the page and got the error

The type or namespace named 'Blog' does not exist in the namespace 'Umbraco.Web.PublishedModels' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I am running the model builder in AppData mode to a custom path so they are not hidden in the AppData folder.

I have tried restarting, changing the mode to PureLive and LiveAppData and still no joy

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Could you explain your environment setup and how you are deploying your site?

Comment: Originally it was setup as a virtual directory but it has now been moved to its own site in IIS, we deploy manually by copying files via FTP

Comment: So are you uploading the whole site through FTP when you deploy or just patching it?  If patching, exactly what are you uploading? Also, is your local site sharing the same database as the live site or are you running 2 separate databases?

Comment: We are just uploading the files that changed, our local host and dev environment share the same database. When I load up the Dev site it says the models are out of date and to rebuild them. Sadly it doesn't fox the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that always catches me out, if you are going to use AppData for your Model builder then you need to always copy across the project Dll's, I thought that just because I was updating views i didn't need to worry, how wrong I was.

Copy across your project Dlls and the error disappears

Comment: Yes indeed. Hence my questions

Answer (score 1):

BTW, you don't need to upload the model .cs files and you shouldn't generate them on the server if you share the database with dev. Only ever generate on dev and then push the dlls.  You would only need the dlls since the models are compiled into the dll.  Don't forget to build the project before you deploy the dlls though.

Also another thing that sometimes happens (but doesn't cause any errors) is that you accidentally upload the ood.flag file in published content models.  If that file is present then models will always show as out of date.

Answer (score 0):

To migrate from PureLive to LiveAppData:

1. Under "appSettings" in the web.config file "Umbraco.ModelsBuilder.ModelsMode" should be set to "LiveAppData".

`<add key="Umbraco.ModelsBuilder.ModelsMode" value="LiveAppData"/>`

2. The contents of the ~/App_Data/Models/ folder should be deleted.
3. The contents of the ~/App_Data/TEMP/ folder should be deleted.
4. Let's run our project. Let's go to Settings > Models Builder pages in the Backoffice and press the "Generate models" button. (Thus, our Models will be created in the ~/App_Data/Models/ folder. However, our project will still not work.)
5. Let's stop our project and include our models in our project.
6. Let's run our project. Well done

I hope it works